# WCF : Service call failed: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, jquery

I am using asp.net 3.5. I have developed the WCF Service. I try to call the WCF Service form JQUERY, But I am getting the error as

Service call failed: 415 Unsupported Media Type

MY Code is as follows:-

IService:-

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    CommandStatus getCommandStatus(string Id, string UnitNumber, string UnitType);
}
```

Service :-

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public CommandStatus getCommandStatus(string Id, string UnitNumber, string UnitType)
    {
        CommandStatus objCommandStatus = new CommandStatus();
        CommandsBLL objCommandsBLL = new CommandsBLL();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = objCommandsBLL.getCommandStatus(Convert.ToInt32(Id), UnitNumber, Convert.ToInt32(UnitType));

        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            objCommandStatus.ID = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IOMH_ID"]);
            objCommandStatus.UnitType = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IOMH_UnitType"]);
        }

        return objCommandStatus;
    }
}
```

Web.Config file is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">  
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and Final my Jquery call is

```
var ID = 10;
        var UnitNumber = '10001';
        var UnitType = 1;

        function CallService() {
           var input =
            {
                    ID: "10",
                    UnitNumber: "10001",
                    UnitType: "1"
            };

            //alert(JSON.stringify(input));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:2878/Mtel_Profiler/Service.svc/getCommandStatus",
                data: JSON.stringify(input),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (userViewModel) {
                    ServiceSucceeded(userViewModel);
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    ServiceFailed(msg);
                }
            });
        }

        function ServiceSucceeded(msg)
        {
            alert('Sucess');
            return false;
        }

        function ServiceFailed(result)
        {
            alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
            return false;
        }
```

Can any one help to resolved this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried above link, but hot helped. I have added teh <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NAMESPACE.AjaxAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors> in my web.config file and not working.

Comment: Did you just copy paste that, or did you change `NAMESPACE` into the namespace of your service?